# Subscribing on changes in new Angular 2 router (>=rc1)

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

For the authentication of my Angular 2 application I subscribed to my router in the application initialisation. I check if a user is set, if it isn't, I try to get a user from my login service, if that also isn't possible I want to go to the login page.

```
ngOnInit() {
    this._router.changes.subscribe(
        next => {
            // First check if our component has a user set
            if (this.loggedInUser === undefined) {
                // It doesn't, let's set this user with help from our loginService
                this.loggedInUser = this._loginService.getUser();

------->        I think that this is where I need to add a line like: 
       if the user now is logged in, finish the change that triggered this code.

                // If user stil isn't set, we need to login
                if (this.loggedInUser === undefined) {
                    // Check if the user isn't already at the login page
                    if (!(this._router.urlTree.contains(this._router.createUrlTree(['login'])))) {
                        console.log('Not authorised, redirected to login.');
                        this._router.navigate(['login']);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    );
}
```

The problem with this solution is that the hard links in my application don't work anymore.

For example:
If I go to localhost:8000/user/1 my application is initialised and my application gets the user from my loginService. It doesn't however go to the link that I entered, I can navigate to this user through the menu. I guess that I need to add a line that tells the router that it should follow the next action? Is this possible with this construction?

Edit: I hope the problem is clearer with this explanation:
If I go to a certain url, for example http://aplication/users/5, the code snippet above is triggered. Most of the time, the user is already logged in and the credentials are retrieved from the loginService. How can I tell the router that it should just finish the change action that triggered the code?

Comment: It's not clear to me what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say just `return;` should do what you want. "The change that triggered this code" is completed already at this point anyway. If you don't navigate explicitly to another path, this should be exactly the result you're asking for.